# Redirect sharepoint page after creating site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, event-handling

I've created a on WebProvisioned event.

At the end i want to do a redirect to a custom page. But this is not as easy as i thougt.

I did:

```
string url = "CustomAdminPage.aspx";    
SPUtility.Redirect(url, SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage, currentContext);
```

The event is Synchronous, so i can use the Httpcontext in the contstructor.

How can i make a redirect from my webprovisioned event?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 9 || DateTime.Now.Hour < 17)
    {
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
        properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/EventReceiver/CustomError.aspx";
    }
}
```

I've found this [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-redirect-to-a-custom-page-for-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Best regards!